# What is the group action of $\prod_i S_{n_i}$ making $\{h\in S_n:h(v)=v'\}$ a principal homogeneous set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, representation-theory

In a paper I'm reading, there is the following setup: Suppose $I$ is a finite set, $I^n$ the set of $n$-tuples of elements in $I$. Pick $v=(v_1,\dots,v_n),v'=(v'_1,\dots,v'_n)\in I^n$. Let $n_i=|\{r:v_r=i\}|$ and $n'_i=|\{r:v'_r=i\}|$, i.e., the number of coordinates of $v$ and $v'$ which equal $i\in I$. Assume that $n_i=n'_i$ for all $i$, so that the set of entries of $v$ and $v'$ are just permutations of one another.

Define $\gamma_i,\gamma'_i\colon\{1,\dots,n_i\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$ to be the increasing maps defined by $v_{\gamma_i(r)}=v'_{\gamma'_i(r)}=i$ for all $r$, so they essentially list out the indices of the coordinates equal to $i$. Set $W=\prod_i S_{n_i}$.

It says the set $E=\{h\in S_n:h(v)=v'\}$ is both a left and right principal homogeneous space under the action of $W$, via $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma'_i$. I suspect $h(v)$ is the action of $S_n$ on $I^n$ by permuting indicies.

Can someone clarify what the action of $W$ on $E$ is via $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_i'$? I can't see why the above is true since I can't find a sensible action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_i'$ define the embeddings of $W$ into $S_n$. The map $\gamma_i$ defines the embedding $W\hookrightarrow(S_n)_\nu\subset S_n$ as the stabilizer of $\nu$ inside $S_n$ (where $S_n$ acts on $I^n$ by permuting the coordinates as you say). Similarly, $\gamma_i'$ defines the embedding $W\hookrightarrow (S_n)_{\nu'}\subset S_n$ as the stabilizer of $\nu'$.

Now, $W$ acts on $E$ on the right via $(S_n)_\nu$ and on the left via $(S_n)_{\nu'}$. But, pick any $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma(\nu)=\nu'$. Then, it is clear that $E$ is just the double coset
$$(S_n)_{\nu'}\sigma(S_n)_\nu\in (S_n)_{\nu'}\backslash S_n/(S_n)_{\nu'}$$ 
so both the left and right actions of $W$ are free.

Comment: Thanks David, Explicilty, how does $\gamma_i$ define the embedding $W\hookrightarrow (S_n)_\nu$? If $(\sigma_i)_i\in W$ is a tuple of permutations $\sigma_i\in S_{n_i}$, does it map to the permutation in $S_n$ defined by acting as $\sigma_i$ on the subset of $n_i$ indices of the coordinates which equal $i$? Since these indices partition $\{1,\dots,n\}$, this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The permutation $\sigma_i$ acts on the image of $\gamma_i$.